# Add multiple fields to form with control form

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a problem when adding a new field with jquery.
the date field is on control form, if I add a new field it is added as a preview but the css loses control on requested, That is, it no longer displays the calender

```
<div class="content-body">
<section id="multiple-column-form">
    <div class="row match-height">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h4 class="card-title">Create a new file</h4></div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-more-form float-end btn btn-primary">ADD MORE</a>
                        </div>
                        <form class="form" method="post" action="script.php">
                            <div class="form-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                            <label for="">InvoiceDate</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="InvoiceDate[]" class="form-control flatpickr-basic flatpickr-input" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" readonly="readonly"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                  
                                </div>
                                <div class="paste-new-forms"></div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <button type="submit"  name="SaveFile" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mb-1">Save</button>
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-warning mr-1 mb-1">Reset</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

$(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).on('click', '.remove-btn', function () {
                $(this).closest('.row').remove();
            });
            var html = '\
                            \
                                \
                                    \
                                        InvoiceDate\
                                        \
                                    \
                                \
                                \
                                    Dlt\
                                \
                            \
                        ';
            
            $(document).on('click', '.add-more-form', function () {
                $('.paste-new-forms').append(html);
            });

        });

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = '\ \ \ \ InvoiceDate\ \ \ \ \ Dlt\ \ \ ';
```

This code means that instead of a new input field, you are adding a line that displays this text. You should generate an input field to append to the relevant node instead.

In the below code I did it by adding a function "addField()". I'll leave the styling to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.remove-btn', function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.add-more-form', function() {
    addField();
  });
});

function addField() {
  var newFieldId = 'field' + $('.paste-new-forms').children().length;
  var newField = $('<div>').attr('id', newFieldId);
  $('<label>').text('InvoiceDate').appendTo(newField);
  $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name: 'InvoiceDate[]', placeholder: 'YYYY-MM-DD'}).appendTo(newField).css('form-control flatpickr-basic flatpickr-input');
  newField.appendTo('.paste-new-forms');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-body">
<section id="multiple-column-form">
    <div class="row match-height">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h4 class="card-title">Create a new file</h4></div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-more-form float-end btn btn-primary">ADD MORE</a>
                        </div>
                        <form class="form" method="post" action="script.php">
                            <div class="form-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                            <label for="">InvoiceDate</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="InvoiceDate[]" class="form-control flatpickr-basic flatpickr-input" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" readonly="readonly"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                  
                                </div>
                                <div class="paste-new-forms"></div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <button type="submit"  name="SaveFile" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mb-1">Save</button>
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-warning mr-1 mb-1">Reset</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```